# React-Native ScrollView works only on react-native-paper items

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, react-native-paper

I don't understand my issue

I'm using ScrollView (from react-native and react-native-gesture-handler, I've tried both), and my page doesn't want to Scroll at all, unless I press and drag on a react-native-paper item (like a [Checkbox](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/checkbox.html) or a [Radio button](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button.html) for example).

Does anyone has encountered the same issue ?

Here is an example of my code :

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
    <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems:"center"}}>
      <Checkbox /> // if I click on this checkbox, then I hold my finger and I scroll, the page will scroll
      <Text>Test</Text> // if I click on this Text, then I hold my finder and I scroll, the page will not scroll
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for reading me

Comment: The view only scrolls if your components, inside this ScrollView, are higher than the screen. In the IOS platform, you have this behavior "I press and drag" if the component is inside the ScrollView.

Comment: Yes I know, this is a short example to not show all my page, but even when my content is higher than the screen, I'm obligated to target on a Checkbox to scroll the page.

Comment: Try to remove the View inside the ScrollView and the width and height style. And use ScrollView from react-native. If not work, I can only catch the problem if you show the original code.

Comment: I've already tried this.
It's a bit hard for me to show my code beause the page is extremly long, do you have an idea for me to show you personnaly the code?